# How to change each element in an array to the mean of the array using NumPy?

Tags: numpy

I am new to Python. In one of my assignment question, part of the question requires us to compute the average of each element in a sub-matrix and replace each element with the mean using operators that's available in Numpy.

An example of the matrix could be

```
M = [[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]],[[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]]
```

Through some operations, it is expected to get a matrix like the following:

```
M = [[[2,2,2],[3,3,3]],[[4,4,4],[5,5,5]]]
```

I have looked at some numpy documentations and still haven't figured out, would really appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options here.  All of them follow the same general idea.  You have an MxNxL array and you want to apply a reduction operation along the last axis that will leave you with an MxN result by default.  However, you want to broadcast that result across the same MxNxL shape you started with.

Numpy has a parameter in most reduction operations that allows you to keep the reduced dimension present in the output array, which will allow you to easily broadcast that result into the correct sized matrix.  The parameter is called `keepdims`, you can read more in the documentation to [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

Here are a few approaches that all take advantage of this.

***Setup***

```
avg = M.mean(-1, keepdims=1)

# array([[[2.],
#         [3.]],
# 
#        [[4.],
#         [5.]]])
```

---

***Option 1***
Assign to a view of the array.  However, it will also coerce float averages to `int`, so cast your array to float first for precision if you want to do this.

```
M[:] = avg
```

---

***Option 2***
An efficient read only view using `np.broadcast_to`

```
np.broadcast_to(avg, M.shape)
```

---

***Option 3***
Broadcasted multiplication, more for demonstration than anything.

```
avg * np.ones(M.shape)
```

---

All will produce (same except for possibly the `dtype`):

```
array([[[2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3.]],

       [[4., 4., 4.],
        [5., 5., 5.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line of code:

```
M.mean(-1, keepdims=1) * np.ones(M.shape)
```

Comment: This is just a copy paste of my last option.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice